# Server to receive emails on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the Google Cloud Platform [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) I read that it has restrictions on sending emails from VMs created on it.

However, I need create a VM with Exim that will only receive emails via SMTP. Does Google Cloud Platform allow having a VM for this purpose?

I searched the documentation and found nothing.

Comment: When you say only using SMTP .. are you sending an email to the phone's number sort of thing?  Cause that is still sending an email, regardless of its destination point.  Or you mean you have access to a carrier's API machine that bypasses the whole email systems entirely?

Comment: My server does not send any emails. But external users send emails to us, and our Exim server is responsible for receiving these emails and handling them.

Comment: Ahh okay, so it is email platform interacting with SMTP, thats how I've usually seen it as well.  Just making sure.  But that sounds like it should work then, because you are only getting emails.  I suspect the only reason this is a "feature" is to stop spambots from going nuts,  but always  the bad apple to ruin the bunch I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud allows **ingress** on port 25 which means you can implement an SMTP server for the receipt of mail.

Egress on port 25 will be blocked.

Just make sure you understand what SMTP is, which is server-to-server mail transfer. Since that means port 25 must be open to the world, you will be hit with a massive number of spam connection attempts. You might find it very expensive paying for that traffic.

You mention: **But external users send emails to us**. No, they won't. Users do not send mail over port 25 unless you have written an application to do so. For the most part, port 25 is universally blocked around the world. Most consumer ISPs block port 25 ingress and egress. Commercial companies usually must apply for an exemption to use port 25 for egress. For an end user to send mail to you on port 25 they must use egress.

I strongly recommend that you rethink your strategy.

[Update]

An IP address with port 25 open will raise concerns. That is the express route to get onto blacklists. To prevent that, you should implement additional DNS resource records so that the IP address to domain mapping can be verified. Doing so makes it even easier for hackers to find your server, so you are in a loop making your address professional but also exposing your address to the world.

Comment: Today I use this Exim server on DigitalOcean, but I want to leave everything under GCP (web servers, database, etc). There I just pay for the VM that exists, nothing else.

As I understand it, so GCP will charge each connection attempt to my server. That's it?

Comment: Google does not charge for connection attempts. Google charges for the network bandwidth consumed by network traffic. A connection (good or bad) consumes bandwidth transferring bytes.

Comment: @Tom - I have successfully run SMTP servers with other vendors. Then one day I find the server is no longer receiving mail. Someone put my IP address on a blacklist. Getting off those lists is like asking the governor for a pardon.

Comment: Today which tactic did you approach to have your email server?

Today I use it this way because I run wildcards mails, that is, a customer can have an email new-order@your-company.example.com, or even reply-order{ID}@your-company.example.com .

I don't use a system with pre-created emails (like Workspace, 365) because for my business model it's impossible to manage each one individually, and everything needs to be via wildcard/dynamic.

Comment: My customers are large enterprises. They can easily obtain exceptions in the cloud or they can host in their own data centers. For myself, I had dedicated physical servers in a shared data center. I stopped hosting my own email servers (Postfix) in 2020 after 20+ years. If your mail server is working, leave it where it is. Changing the IP address could introduce new problems.